# spring can not view jsp files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I have two controllers one that lead to jsp files and the other to the normal method. I can access method with other controller but not method for jsp controller. I have follow proper layout of files and folders as suggested by [Spring official Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class) . I am using **Visual Studio Code** for development.

whenever I try to view the jsp files in my browser I get the below error.

[image: Error]

Below is my **application.properties** file configuration

```
server.port=2121
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I have added the below dependency as suggested

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>jstl</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Below is the layout image of files and folders.

[image: layout]

**JspController.java**

```
 package com.jairini.demojairini.controllers;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class JspController {
  
  @RequestMapping(value ="/home")
  public String toHomepageJsp(){
    return "homepage";
}

  @GetMapping("/view")
  public String toIndexJsp() {
    return "index";
}
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
 package com.jairini.demojairini.controllers;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

 @RestController
 public class HomeController {

 @GetMapping("/")
  public String home(){
    return "mambo vipi";
}

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>Habari gani from JSP</h1>
        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**homepage.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html>
 <body>
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>Nzuri sana from JSP</h1>
        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Updates**

**Application.java**

```
  package com.jairini.demojairini;
  import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
  import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

  @SpringBootApplication
  public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

 }
```

I have spent **hrs** through a lot of guides and post on the above error with no success. I am new to web Application.

Comment: Did you also follow the doc regarding, building a war and not a jar, and have the proper `SpringBootServletInitializer` extends for bootstrapping. If you don't run a war it won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum honestly i didn't, Can you give me a technical clue on this. Also thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank. I have gone through the doc regarding building a war and jar in spring as you suggested, and I found out that I was doing quite wrong . I spent almost a day without noticing this . Thanks once again.